# Upgrading to CDH 5 from CDH 4.5

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I've been contemplating on upgrading to CDH 5 (from CDH 4.5) to prepare ourselves for Spark. I worry about the data already in my HDFS. In Cloudera documentation, it says that you have to back up the HDFS metadata indicated by `dfs.name dir` (or `dfs.namenode.name.dir`) in **hdfs-site.xml**. The problem is: there's no such entry in my **hdfs-site.xml**

Can anybody tell me how to go about upgrading to CDH 5 without harming my existing data in HDFS? Thanks.

Comment: Could you link the Cloudera documentation your are referring to?